# Issue accessing node server on port 80(dynamic port)

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, dns, port, iptables

I set up a node server on an AWS ec2 instance and i'm able to access this server by using 
"public-ip:3000" ("3000" being my node server running port) but i want to be able to access it without specifying my port instead, this will enable my DNS access the node server too. i already tried re-routing on my IP table with this "sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000" but i still can't access the server on ports 80

Answer (score 0):

As port 80 will be used for http by web servers like apache or nginx, 
u better try to not to make the node server to directly listen on port 80.

To accomplish properly, 
u should install these 2
 1. web server like apache or tomcat and 
 2. app server like phusion passenger which supports ruby, nodejs, etc.

By installing and configuring these above, u can achieve in the following way

> Apache listens on port 80
>
> phusion passenger config mentioned in the virtual hosts file of apache
>   will connect the request to the corresponding node application

apache ref - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart

phusion passenger ref - https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/apache/install/oss/xenial/